# CSS Vertical Align Image Right

Tags: css, html

I am trying to align an image to the right of a div, the div is not set as a specific height and neither is the image, the image is user generated.

Anyway, I tried using the old HTML4 method for aligning an image to the right of a div:

```
<img src="link" align="right" />
```

And after some reading I found out that it wasn't supported in HTML5, so I then read on and found out that there is a CSS style called **vertical align**, I tried adding that to my image like so:

```
<img src="link" style="vertical-align:right;" />
```

But that didn't manage to work.

I simply want the image to move to the right of the div.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "align an image to the right of a div". Please provide a picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Another Solution beside of `float`:**

```
<div id="ParentImg">
<img src="link"/> 
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#ParentImg {
text-align: right;
}
```

**or:**

```
<div style="text-align:right;">
<img src="link"/> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Vertically align to right? doesn't seem right to me. You can use float right on the image or text-align:right on the parent div.

Comment: Thing is that I am running this through bbcode. So this is the creation for a php signature system so if it is floated it will ruin the threads layout, if it is floated + cleared it will also ruin the layout. @Bodgan (adding to that if it is text-aligned then the image has to be housed in a div, that will then ruin the look of the signature)

Comment: Can you make a fiddle for the signature?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `<span></span>` tag instead of `<div>` tag and then change the styles of it.

```
<span style='text-align:right'>
    <img src="link"  />
</span>
```